# Composer is not getting my new PHP version

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install a package that requires PHP ^7.0. So I changed my host PHP version from 5.6 to 7.0.25. Running `php -v` return:

> PHP 7.0.25 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2017 17:10:45) ( NTS )

But composer still relating version problem:

> - spatie/laravel-backup 4.19.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: what  are you using WAMP or XAMPP?

Comment: This is in my production host

Comment: have you checked php info for version of the php

Comment: `phpinfo()` show 7.0.25 as version

Comment: can search with 5.6.30 in ur total PHP and check from where composure taking PHP.........try like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably still have php5.6-cli installed on your server (`which php`)
It should work if you call

```
/path/to/php7 composer.phar update
```

**Or**

Considering php7 executable is /usr/bin/php7.0, create an alias in your ~/.bash_profile

```
alias composer='/usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/local/bin/composer'
```

**Or**

By default, composer (composer.phar generally located in /usr/local/bin/composer) uses the executable specified by env :

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

You can also specify a targeted version of php to use :

```
#!/usr/bin/php7.0
```

**Or**

completely remove php5.6-cli :)